# A question on the Particular Integral in a second order differential equation with a particular case

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I have a second order differential equation that I had to solve. For example here is one that I have below.

$$y''+2y'=3$$

The auxilliary equation which becomes:

$$m^2+2m=0$$
$$m(m+2)=0$$
$$m_1=-2, m_2=0$$

Then I tried to find the particular integral of the function. I tried to solve it until I got here where being that $m_2$ is 0 which you have to multiply the particular integral by x so it becomes:

$$ P.I = \lambda x$$

If I don't multiply by a x term in this case, I yield a case where I can't solve it:

$$ y = \lambda$$
$$ y'' = y' = 0$$
Putting into the function:
$$ 0 + 2(0) = 3$$

Where I have a contradiction case. Why is it that for a case where the complementary function where the solution of the auxilliary equation is 0 that we have the multiply by x? By what theorem is this under?

Comment: $$y'' + 2y' = 3 \Longleftrightarrow (e^{2x}y')' = 3e^{2x}$$